# How do I send custom data in react-router goBack method like push and replace methods?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am using react-router-dom v4 and able to send custom data to the new screen using `push(path, state)` and `replace(path, state)` methods in "props.history.location"

I want to send the data back to the previous screen but could not achieve using `go(n)` or `goBack()` or `goForward()`.

How can I solve the scenario when I need to send data back to the previous screen?

Comment: did you find any good solution for this? (without localstorage)

Comment: Not yet. In mobile apps like flutter, I can find a solution for the exact requirements, but I couldn't find any solution for the web.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can pass params directly when going back.

However, it is possible to accomplish this in different ways.

You can implement `redux` and have an action/reducer for this. (requires some boilerplate work)

Or easier, you can store your data in `localstorage` and read it in the page. Be careful to use `async` for localstorage when reading data.

These two should work.

Answer (score 0):

use replace instead of push maybe.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is complicated because security reasons. The app should not know what happen when somebody clicks "back" - so you shouldn't be able to manipulate with that state either.

BUT

here is a workaround doing what you need:

```js
history.replace(`/previous/url`, { state });
setTimeout(() => history.goBack());
```

- you will need to have stored the previous url
- the state will be available only for first render, so you have to store it in state

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I didn't find any official suggestion to achieve this, following is my workaround.
In the following code snippet I keep track of locations in history stack(since there is no direct way to get the history stack)

```
import {Switch, useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Action, History, Location } from "history";
const history = useHistory();
const locations = [];
locations.push(history.location);//since the first location is not passed to the listener we have to initialize the locations like this to keep record of the first page that user loads
history.listen((location: Location, action: Action) => {
        if (Action.Push == action) {
            locations.push(location);
        } else if (Action.Pop == action) {
            locations.pop();
        } else if (Action.Replace == action) {
            locations.pop();
            locations.push(location);
        }
    })
```

Then I write the following back method which receives a payload that is going to be passed to the previous page.

```
import _ from 'lodash'; 
export const back = (state) => {
    if (!history) {
        throw 'History was not set';
    }
    const uniqueLocations = _.uniqBy(locations, (l: Location) => l.key);//for some reason there will be duplicates in the locations array, using uniqBy method of lodash, we can remove the duplicates
    
    if (uniqueLocations.length >= 2) {
        const targetLocation = uniqueLocations[uniqueLocations.length - 2];
        history.go(-1);
        history.push({
            ...targetLocation,
            state: {
                ...targetLocation.state,
                backState: state,
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Now calling the `back()` method will pass the state argument of the back method to the previous screen which can be accessed like this: `props.location.state.backState` in the previous screen.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the information about the previous route as `state` whenever you change the page. To avoid code duplication, you might create a custom hook that wraps `history-push`. It could look something like this:

```
import { useHistory, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

export const useRouter = () => {
  const history = useHistory()
  const location = useLocation()

  const push = (url: string, state?: any) => {
    history.push(url, { ...state, from: location.pathname })
  }

  return { push }
}
```

Now, when changing the page using the custom hook:

```
  const { push } = useRouter()

  <button onClick={() => push("/profile")}> Go to profile </button>
```

You will be able to access the previous route:

```
  const location = useLocation()
  console.log(location.state) // { from: '/previous-path' }
```

Having `from` in state, you could navigate to the previous page and pass some info there:

```
push(location.state.from, { foo: 'bar' })
```

Answer (score -2):

`goBack() or go(-1)` are used to Go back to the previous history entry. If you want to send new data to the previous route, you might as well use `history.push({pathname: prevPath, state: {data: 1}})`;

the `prevPath` is what you might pass on to the `nextRoute` using a `location state`.

Comment: This approach will consider it as a new entry and will add to history stack and history length will increase. When I hit back button, the back navigation flow may be affected.